# Избавиться от дублирования INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, postgresql

БД Postgresql

```
CREATE TABLE items (
    id SERIAL,
    user_id INTEGER,
    status SMALLINT
);

CREATE TABLE phones (
  phone VARCHAR(12),
  users INTEGER[]
);
```

Где items.status принимает значения 3, 5 или 7

Необходимо для списка phone1, phone2... сделать выборку следующего вида

phone1;COUNT(items.id) где status=3 ;COUNT(items.id) где status=7
phone2;COUNT(items.id) где status=3 ;COUNT(items.id) где status=7
...

Мой вариант плодит дубли и потом суммирует

```
SELECT phones.phone as phone, COUNT(it1.id) as saled_count, COUNT(it2.id) as not_saled_count
FROM phones
INNER JOIN items it1 ON phones.users @> ARRAY[it1.user_id]::int[]
INNER JOIN items it2 ON phones.users @> ARRAY[it2.user_id]::int[]
WHERE phones.phone IN ('phone1', 'phone2')
    AND it1.status = 7 AND it2.status = 3
GROUP BY phones.phone;
```

Результат, соответственно

```
phone1    5    5
phone2    6    6
...
```

Вместо

```
phone1    3    2
phone2    5    1
...
```

Ну и сам вопрос: как правильно составить запрос?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял задачу

```
select
    p.phone,
    sum(case i.status when 3 then 1 else 0 end) as status3,
    sum(case i.status when 5 then 1 else 0 end) as status5,
    sum(case i.status when 7 then 1 else 0 end) as status7
from phones as p
inner join items as i on i.user_id = any(p.users)
where p.phone in ('phone1', 'phone2')
group by p.phone;
```

Comment: Гениально. Просто нет слов.

Comment: Просто я недавно сталкивался с похоже задачей :) Если ответ вам помог, отметьте его решением.

Comment: CASE необязателен, можно просто **SUM(i.status=3) AS status3**.